# 1 Year range, how can I add up and group Unix Timestamp records into 1 day interval results?

Tags: sql

I have a table full of records that are marked with timestamps. When given the date range of 1 year, I need to build a query that can add up the 'Volume' column, return max value for 'High' records, return first record of 'Open', return min value for 'Low' records, and very last record of 'Close' for every day(These calculations would be made for every 24 hours) and return 365 records, each record representing 1 day.

If this query was adaptable to adding up and returning 1 Week intervals (returning 52 records representing 52 weeks for the entire year, more or less), and 1 Month intervals as well that would be extremely helpful.

The database might be missing data for majority of the year, but hopefully SQL is smart enough to use the data it can find.

This is for tradingview chart to return data points. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated!

I'm completely lost on how to accomplish this.. I'm using SQL server it seems many of the examples I found on google have functions that are not supported.

This is my very basic query for getting data between x times:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Market 
WHERE AssetPairId = '1' AND [Time] BETWEEN '1565521380' AND '1566334368'
```

Table design:

```
MaketId, Volume, High, Low, [Open], AssetPairId, [Close], Time
```

Example Data:

```
MarketId, Volume, High, Low, [Open], AssetPairId, [Close], Time
1 980000000 100000000   100000000   100000000   1   100000000   1565521380
```

**This is for SQL SERVER**

UPDATE:

Here's my new attempt.. doesn't seem to work, I can't get it to show aggregated 1 day intervals.

```
SELECT
    [Time] = floor(([Time] / 86400) * 86400),
    Volume = SUM(Volume),
    Low =  MIN (Low),
    High = MAX (High),
    [Open] = MIN([Open]),
    [Close] = MAX([Close])
FROM Market p WHERE [Time] BETWEEN '1534774061' AND '1566310061'
GROUP BY [Time]
```

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle? What version?

Comment: I added more info! Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you would convert the timestamp column to a date:

```
select convert(date, timestampcol) as dte, sum(col1), . . .
from t
group by convert(date, timestampcol)
order by convert(date, timestampcol);
```

Comment: If you want do the report by week once you have a date you use `SELECT DATEPART( wk, @Dt)` for month `MONTH()`

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your unix column to datetime column first. Than you can select with the desired built in functions the desired precision. In my example hour wise.

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, datetime_column) AS year,
   DATEPART(month, datetime_column) AS month,
   DATEPART(day, datetime_column) AS day,
   DATEPART(hour, datetime_column) AS hour,
   COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
   SELECT DATEADD(second, unix_timestamp_column, '19700101') AS datetime_column
FROM your_table
) AS t
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, datetime_column),
     DATEPART(month, datetime_column),
     DATEPART(day, datetime_column),
     DATEPART(hour, datetime_column)
```

Comment: When your timestamp has milliseconds,, you maybe have to cut the last three digits with the LEFT function (depends on your sql version): `DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(d.timems, 10)) - DATEDIFF(SECOND ,GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE())`